# Weird strings that cause a newline but there is no control char

Tags: python, string

While running a python script I came across a very confusing string that, when concatenated with other strings, didn't result in a string of the combined length.

```
s = "testtesttest " + s + " helloworld"
```

This concat resulted in (s being the string in question)

```
 helloworldt Steaks im heißen Öl \"ohne Salz\" auf jeder Seite 3 Minuten scharf anbraten.
```

So I let the python script print it to a file and I looked for invisible characters or control characters that may cause this behavior but nothing.

The value of `s` is:

> Steaks im heißen Öl \"ohne Salz\" auf jeder Seite 3 Minuten scharf
>   anbraten.

Pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/raw/g3EN7Yy7

You can try it out yourself by pasting it into a file and printing it to a linux terminal with `cat`. Why is it behaving like that? The failed concat causes my python program to not work and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Try `s.encode()`.

Comment: Works fine for me in python3. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Also works in python2, but is not automatically decoded

Comment: Also works on the terminal `cat <(echo "Steaks im heißen Öl \"ohne Salz\" auf jeder Seite 3 Minuten scharf anbraten.")`

Comment: @smac89 A moderator just removed my pastebin link that I used because pasting it into the question was removing the unknown behaviour. But @glibdud hinted me at using `s.encode()`to check the string, that showed me a single carriage return at the end of the sting, that caused the problem. I suppose it was text from a macOS, that still uses \r for new lines

Comment: Yea generally, when working with foreign characters, you either need to do it in python3, or make use of `str.decode` and `str.encode` to get the correct values

Comment: I was using python3, why would it prevent the \r carriage return from doing what it does, the problem for me was, that the editor I used automatically adjusted to a normal newline so I didn't see the problem until I looked at the bytestring